# My python program have difficulty about convert list to int

Tags: python

I’m having a problem with this code:

```
import random  
right = random.randint(1, 100)
mid = random.choice("+-")
equal = "="
left = random.randint(1, 100)
a = [right, mid, left, equal]
a = str(a)
a = int(a) # Error here
```

I get the below error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "[62, '+', 82, '=']"
```

Comment: You cannot convert things like `=` to an int. What are you trying to accomplish? Produce an int result of your list?

Comment: The code as written attempts the convert the string "[62, '+', 82, '=']" to an int, which of course won't work. What are you expecting to obtain as a result? It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you want to gather the elements of a formula and then get the result of that formula. And it looks like you're close.  First, we don't actually need the equal sign:  `a = [right, mid, left]`.  Next, we need to get these things all into a big string `all_strings = map(lambda x: str(x), a)` so that we can get the result: `eval(' '.join(all_strings))`

```
import random  
right = random.randint(1, 100)
mid = random.choice("+-")
left = random.randint(1, 100)
a = [right, mid, left]
all_strings = map(lambda x: str(x), a)
print(eval(' '.join(all_strings)))
```

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate a string like "[12, '-', 56, '=']" as a list I suggest you use `iteral_eval()`. Also, the `except` is used to handle the non-numeric cases:

```
import ast
import random  
right = random.randint(1, 100)
mid = random.choice("+-")
equal = "="
left = random.randint(1, 100)
a = [right, mid, left, equal]
a
#[12, '-', 56, '=']
a = str(a) #Error may happened here
a
#"[12, '-', 56, '=']"
a = ast.literal_eval(a)
b = []
for x in list(a):
   try:
     b.append(int(x))
   except:
     b.append(x)

a = b 
a
#[12, '-', 56, '=']
```

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is you are trying to convert your list `[62, '+', 82, '=']` into the string `"62+82="` and then evaluate it. As @mchen.ja noted, calling `str` on a list just puts the passed list into quotes. It doesn’t merge the values.

To combine the two values using the given operation, you can use the `eval` built in, which parses the string as a line of python code and returns the result. To take this approach, however, you need to omit the equals sign.

```
import random  
right = random.randint(1, 100)
mid = random.choice("+-")
left = random.randint(1, 100)
a = [right, mid, left]
merged_a = ''.join([str(i) for i in a]) # Have a look at the join function.
a = eval(merged_a) # Returns the result of the created expression
```